# Select text input without input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to select a text area when I press '/' but when I do that it does it but also puts the slash in the box which I don't want.

```
   document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
       if (e.key === '/') document.getElementById("box").select()
   });
```

I've tried select, focus, and click. It selects the input text area, but it puts the slash as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `keyup` instead:

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    if (e.key === '/') document.getElementById("box").select()
});
```

**Edit:**

**Reason:** The `KeyboardEvent.key` event follows a sequence in the execution of the different types of events:

- `keydown`
- `beforeinput` (only on editable content like `<input>`, `<textarea>`, etc.)
- `input` (only on editable content like `<input>`, `<textarea>`, etc.)
- `keyup`

See [KeyboardEvent sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#keyboardevent_sequence) for further details.

So the thing that happens when using `keydown` in your scenario is:

- `keydown`: `box` gets selected
- `beforeinput`: fires because the active element is an editable element, but nothing happens
- `input`: fires because the active element is an editable element + inserting the `/` into `box`
- `keyup`: fires but nothing happens

When using `keyup` instead:

- `keydown`: fires but nothing happens
- `beforeinput`: **doesn't fire** because the active element is **NOT** an editable element
- `input`: **doesn't fire** because the active element is **NOT** an editable element
- `keyup`: `box` gets selected

**Edit:** If you want to be able to use `/` inside the `box`, first check that `box` is not the active element (although it would make it impossible to use `/` in other `input`'s, but I think this is a completely different topic):

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    const box = document.getElementById("box")
    if (e.key === '/' && box !== document.activeElement) box.select()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an event listener to monitor the textarea for the character, and if it's detected, replace it with an empty string. Of course, this will prevent anyone from actually typing that character in the field as well, but it sounds like that might be what you want.

Example:

```js
let textArea = document.getElementById("textArea");

// listen for keyup, if slash pressed, select text
textArea.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "/") {
    textArea.select();
  }
});

// listen for input, replace slash with empty string
textArea.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  textArea.value = textArea.value.replaceAll("/", "");
})
```

```html
<textarea rows="3" id="textArea">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using your listener like this would select the input field every time a user presses the "/"-Key

you should add "e.preventDefault()" to avoid displaying the character in the field.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
       e.preventDefault();
       if (e.key === '/') document.getElementById("box").select()
       [...]/* Logic here if you want the slash as a valid character */

   });
```

Comment: That caused errors, but I messed around and found it I think.

Comment: This will prevent entering *any* key.

Comment: @connexo You're right. I am sorry, did not tried it beforehand. Thanks for your comment!