# What is the decent way of avoiding a pressed key getting displayed when focusing on input element?

Tags: javascript, html, focus, onfocus

I am working on a project where an input field needs to be focused when a specific key is pressed. The problem is when the key is pressed, it also gets displayed in the input field. For example, we have an input element whose value is "some text" and if user presses 1 on his/her keyboard when the input element is not the active element, it becomes "some text1". I do not want the key to be displayed.

I have solved the problem using setTimeout method in order to create a delay, but I am still looking for a better solution. The part of the code can be seen below. userInput refers to the HTML input element that needs to be focused when specific key is pressed which triggers handleInputFocus function to get called.

```
export function handleInputFocus()
{
    if (document.activeElement.id === "user-input")
    {
        userInput.blur(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        setTimeout(() => {
            userInput.focus(); 
        }, 1); 
    }
}
```

I have visited stackoverflow for related questions and mdn (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) to check if focus method takes a parameter that might solve the problem in the first place but I could not find anything useful. I'll be appreciated if anyone can help me out since this feature comes in handy sometimes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so cancel the event. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404583/stop-keypress-event

Comment: ^^ check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault, it would fit well in your else statement

Comment: I answered a similar question [Select text input without input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74064779/select-text-input-without-input/74065009#74065009), does that help?

Comment: @Bqardi not exactly since the same key is also used for focusing out (blur method in if statement), thus the key will be displayed and then the input element will be focused out when keyup is used.